# Create Image from CIS Image - what's Plan Info for SharedImageVersion type?

Tags: azure, azure-image-builder

I have successfully created a non-CIS virtual machine from the Azure marketplace (Windows Server 2022 Datacenter -x64 Gen2).

The objective is take a CIS image and use Azure Image Builder to create a golden (base) image.

From what I have tried and read, it doesn’t look like it’s possible to take a [CIS L1 or L2](https://www.cisecurity.org/benchmark/microsoft_windows_server) Azure marketplace image and customize it with Azure Image Builder:

[CIS Windows 2019 Azure Images not supported by Packer](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/9363)

[custom_data_file for Windows](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/8626)

I am hoping the work-around is that we:

1. Create a vm from a CIS L1 Azure marketplace image
2. Enable WinRM
3. Sysprep and generalize the vm
4. Create a custom image and store it in the Azure image gallery
5. Use Azure Image Builder to customize a golden image

In step #5, I started with the Source looking like this:

```
"source": {
  "type": "SharedImageVersion",
  "imageVersionID": "/subscriptions/somesubid/resourceGroups/myRg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/mygal/images/mywinimage/versions/latest"
},
```

Encountered a deployment failure.

**VMMarketplaceInvalidInput : Creating a virtual machine from Marketplace image or a custom image sourced from a Marketplace image requires Plan information in the request.**

I am unable to find documentation on what does [SharedImageVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/image-builder-json?tabs=bicep%2Cazure-powershell#sharedimageversion-source) looks like with planInfo.

Here’s my guess:

```
"source": {
  "type": "SharedImageVersion",
  "imageVersionID": "/subscriptions/somesubid/resourceGroups/myRg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/galleries/mygal/images/mywinimage/versions/latest",
  "planInfo": {
    "planName": "cis-windows-server-2022-l1",
    "planProduct": "cis-windows-server-2022-l1-gen2",
    "planPublisher": "center-for-internet-security-inc"
  }
},
```

Again, got the same error:

**VMMarketplaceInvalidInput : Creating a virtual machine from Marketplace image or a custom image sourced from a Marketplace image requires Plan information in the request.**

Do you know how it should look like for [SharedImageVersion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/image-builder-json?tabs=bicep%2Cazure-powershell#sharedimageversion-source) for plan info or is there another approach?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Created Azure virtual machine non-cis and generalized the vm:

To generalize vm -> connect with virtual machine -> Win+R -> type sysprep and select ***generalize*** and ***shutdown*** like below:

[image]

Deallocated the virtual machine click on capture to create an image.

[image]

In the image create a gallery or select existing gallery, in the target vm image definition create a custom image with Publisher, offer, SKU like below:

[image]

Once deployed on your resource group in vm definition click on version you can create custom image vm directly.

[image]

[image]

Or you can create a virtual machine, in image select shared image like below:

[image]

Now, custom image sourced from a Marketplace image deployed successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the love @Imran. However, I need to automate this process (it works for non-CIS images), and the way I'm doing this is through Azure Image Builder (AIB). The AIB service runs and fails on the error msg above. Thanks!

Comment: In this [CIS benchmark](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?search=center%20for%20internet%20security&page=1&filters=partners) if you select windows server 2019 its is [supported](https://i.imgur.com/m68bggB.png) in windows server 2022 is not [supporting](https://i.imgur.com/ngLAYEh.png) try to create on different server

Comment: are you saying that CIS 2019 is supported, but not CIS 2022? So, you want me to try creating a custom image from CIS 2019? Please help me understand what you're saying. Thanks!

Comment: Yes try to create on cis 2019

Comment: I think there's something wrong with the image "CIS STIG Benchmark on Microsoft Windows Server 2019", I tried to create a vm, and it was a 2016 server!